# How to display a picture completely in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried many approaches to no avail (commented lines). Any other ideas?

[image: screenshot]

Get the picture first via curl `curl https://i.imgur.com/VYdf3vp.png --output pic.png`

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label, PhotoImage,Canvas

# Create the main window
window = Tk()
window.title("Image Viewer")
window.geometry("600x600")

# Load and display the image
# curl https://i.imgur.com/VYdf3vp.png --output pic.png
image = PhotoImage(file="./pic.png")
label = Label(window, image=image)
# Doesn't help
# label = Label(window, image=image, anchor="nw", padx=10, pady=10)
label.pack()

# Doesn't help
# label.config(width=image.width(), height=image.height())

# Doesn't help
# desired_width = image.width()
# desired_height = image.height()
# label.config(width=desired_width, height=desired_height)

# Doesn't help
# label.place(x=0, y=0, width=desired_width, height=desired_height)

# Doesn't help
# canvas = Canvas(window, width=image.width(), height=image.height())
# canvas.pack()
# canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=image)

# Start the tkinter event loop
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `Pillow` module to load the image and resize it to what you want.

Comment: If you want to avoid needing an external module, you could try `image = image.subsample(2)` before creating the Label - but this only handles integer scaling, and is simply throwing away pixels rather than averaging them together so the results will be poor on some images.